# Get Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80] message when running apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Tags: server

I just bought a new Dell computer and installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on it.  I am trying to install ubuntu-restricted-extras with the command sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras but get the following output:

```
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavutil56 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Ign:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libswresample3 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavcodec-extra58 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Ign:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavformat58 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Err:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libflite1 amd64 2.1-release-3
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Ign:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libpostproc55 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Ign:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libswscale5 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Ign:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavfilter7 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Ign:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavcodec-extra amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavutil56 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libswresample3 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavcodec-extra58 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavformat58 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libpostproc55 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libswscale5 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavfilter7 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavcodec-extra amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavutil56_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libswresample3_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavcodec-extra58_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavformat58_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/flite/libflite1_2.1-release-3_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libpostproc55_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libswscale5_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavfilter7_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavcodec-extra_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have tried running apt-get update and tried with --fix-missing and still get the same error.  I have tried running apt-get clean and that changed the error messages a little bit but still basically the same problem.  I have tried with a VPN on and off.  I have pinged IP address 91.189.91.39 and get 0% packet loss and I can browse the internet without any issues.  In the GUI Software and Updates window, Multiverse Software has been selected and I changed the server from China to Server from United States.

What can I do to fix this?  Thanks

Comment: Maybe you have some external firewall? or some smart proxy in your network?

Comment: Well, I live in China, so there is certainly a firewall.  But I tried it with a vpn and still had the same problem.  Not really sure what a smart proxy might be?  Im just using the wifi at home

Comment: Can you access other USA based sites?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  Yes, it was a problem with my vpn setttings